# Is this function call really ambiguous?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I'm learning about multiple inheritance and the diamond problem, and when I make a function call from the most derived class Visual Studio tells me that the call is ambiguous:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void aFunction() { cout << "I am A\n"; }
};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};

int main()
{
   D DObj;
   DObj.aFunction();             //  This is an ambiguous call
}
```

I understand if I had overridden the base class function in the B and C classes then the call would be ambiguous, but isn't "aFunction()" the same in B and C?

Also, making B and C inherit from A virtually makes the error go away. But my understanding of the keyword "virtual" when inheriting, ie., (Derived : virtual Base), is that it prevents a "more derived class" further down the chain from inheriting multiple copies of a Base up the chain. In inheritance multiple copies of member variables can be inherited, but only one copy of a function with the same name. So for example I could have 5 Derived classes each deriving from Base, and then a MostDerivedClass inheriting from all the 5 Derived classes, in the MostDerivedClass I would have 5 copies of the Base class "member variables", but only one copy of a function with the same name.

So in other words the "virtual" keyword for inheritance should prevent multiple Base "member variable" copies. I don't understand why it would clear up an ambiguous function call in this case.

EDIT: Thank you, it's slowly sinking in. It was impossible for me to imagine "two copies" of A in D, because A is empty (no size). But then I remembered that C++ never creates empty classes, on my setup for example an empty class has size 1. Then I was able to imagine "two copies" of A in D, and it's starting to make sense now.

Comment: I think that without virtual you have 2 identical copies of the function (though this is still something I have to study myself)

Comment: Yes, that's right. D contains two instances of A. The compiler doesn't know if you want to call D::B::A::aFunction or D::C::A::aFunction. Although the function called would be the same in either case, the different invocations would get a different `this` pointer. If you make the derivations from A virtual, then you'll only have one A and no ambiguity. `struct B : virtual A {};` and `struct C : virtual A {};`.

Comment: And (just to prove this is not an issue with the Visual C++ compiler), GCC 5.1 gives [the same error](http://ideone.com/9QYJwy)

Comment: *Is this function call really ambiguous?* -- If a compiler that is used by thousands around the world got something as simple as this wrong using your sample code, you would know about it, believe me.

Comment: You have what is called _the dreaded diamond_ [Here is a good tidbit](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond) on it.

Comment: Imagine if `A` had a member variable and `aFunction` printed it out

Answer (score 5):

The call is ambiguous because there are two possible `A` base objects that could be passed as the `this` argument of the call.  Even though it is the same physical function that ulitimately get called, and that function completely ignores its `this` argument, the fact that there are two of them makes it ambiguous.

Using `virtual` inheritance means that there would be only one `A` base object, so then the call would not be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Because multiple copies of member variables are inherited, you could have two separate copies of a function with different behavior.

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    virtual void aFunction() { cout << "I am A with value " << x ; }
};
struct B : A {
};
struct C : A {
};
struct D : B, C {};

int main()
{
   D DObj;
   ((B*)(&DObj))->x = 0; // set the x in B to 0
   ((C*)(&DObj))->x = 1; // set the x in C to 1
   DObj.aFunction();             //  This is an ambiguous call
}
```

Should this output 0 or 1?

The compiler could detect the specific case of an inline function that does not reference this, but you can easily work around the issue so its not worth the complexity for a relatively rare case.

Comment: In your example wouldn't it matter if D called B's constructor or A's constructor last? This is confusing, but if when D is constructed it calls B's constructor, then C's constructor, then the answer should be 1. And 0 if it calls them the other way?

Comment: The point is there are two copies of the x member variable, so which version should aFunction reference?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice If you do not inherit A virtually, there are two copies of A, one in B and one in C, so you have two copies of x. When you access through D, it is ambigous which version of x to access.

Comment: @user1937197 Ah, yes, thanks, I see now. There are two copies of x member. But in my example there was no member variable in the base class, so if there are two copies of Base it it makes it harder to visualise exactly what's happening. I'm still not understanding it.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice The compilier is treating it exactly the same as if there was a member, so there are two potential this values to pass.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm slowly starting to come round. I'm picturing that an empty class has size 1, and there are two copies of the Base class. If the Base class doesn't have any size because it doesn't have any member variables I'm finding it hard to imaging two copies of a zero-sized class.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice Classes are always at least 1 byte long to avoid that sort of issue. So even if there are no members, the compilier will add 1 byte of padding to give the class actual size.

Comment: @user1937198: that is actually not correct, but it's reasonable to pretend that it is. If a non-virtual base class has no members, then it might not occupy any space in an object of a derived class. That doesn't violate the principle that an object must occupy space, because the derived object does have a non-zero size (even if *it* has no members). That only works for base objects. A member object must have a non-zero size.

Comment: @rici I didn't know that. Just curiosity, it there anyway to observe that the base class has zero size in a way that is distinguishable from the base class padding overlapping the child class members?

Comment: @user1937198: Essentially, it's legal because it's not detectable :) In cases where you could see that it was happening, it's not legal (for example, if the first member of the derived class has the same type as the empty base class.) See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo for some explanation and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ea10fc8b8f6c00f for an interesting example of it's utility (tuples are implemented with inheritance precisely to allow this possibility).

Answer (score 0):

use the virtual inheritance to solve the diamond prolem:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    virtual void aFunction() { cout << "I am A with value " << x ; }
};
struct B : virtual A { // add virtual
};
struct C : virtual A { // virtual
};
struct D : B, C {};
```